# How can I find the application for a MIME type on linux?

Tags: mime-types, freedesktop

Is there a linux API that can find the default application for a MIME type? Then I can use this application to open a file.

I can not use xdg-open(url) because the file format is a wrapper format and shared mime-type can only tell the wrapper MIME type. The embedded mime type can only be got from the wrapper file header.

The process would be like: 1. find embedded mime type 2. mime-open(embedded mime type, url)

Is it possible?

Comment: I can't find the MIME type for a pdf extension. So I the question is worthless to me, and also the answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `xdg-mime` command is used to query or set file associations.

```
jinx:735 Z$ xdg-mime query default application/pdf  
evince.desktop
```

Comment: This is a good answer, because this program is specifically designed to work across popular desktop environments (KDE, Gnome, others). It's part of a set of related tools called "Portland", a.k.a. xdg-utils, from http://portland.freedesktop.org/wiki/.

Comment: Also note that it's a (long) shell script, so if you want to find out how to get the information for a specific desktop environment, you can read it to find out.