# How to properly and easily configure `xdg-open` without any environment?

Tags: files, arch-linux, configuration, mime-types, freedesktop

I'm using OpenBox window manager **without any desktop environment**.

**`xdg-open`** behaves strangely. It opens everything with `firefox`.

```
$ xdg-settings --list
Known properties:
  default-web-browser           Default web browser
```

I'm looking for a simple program; something like reading every **`*.desktop`** file in **`/usr/share/applications/`** folder and automatically setting xdg settings.

Comment: using `xdg-mime` (part of `xdg-utils`) is the best answer for working with (querying, configuring) `xdg-open`. See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8793/how-can-i-find-the-application-for-a-mime-type-on-linux

Comment: In case someone else has this issue with `xdg-open` opening everything in Firefox, simply deleting `~/.config/mimeapps.list` and restarting [fxed it for me](https://askubuntu.com/a/1299260/1070704) (in Ubuntu 20.04).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can install and use [perl-file-mimeinfo](http://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/any/perl-file-mimeinfo/) in the `extra` repository to manage mimetypes.

Example to open all `.pdf` files in `apvlv`:

```
/usr/bin/vendor_perl/mimeopen -d $file.pdf
```

or on other Linux distributions where `mimeopen` is NOT in `/usr/bin/vendor_perl/` but is in one of the `$PATH` directories :

```
mimeopen -d $file.pdf
```

and then, at the prompt, enter the application: `apvlv`.

Comment: It work's. But it only opens file. So my `xdg-open` left unconfigured and applications using `xdg-open` won't open files right.

Comment: I don't quite follow your comment. What is not working? The `-d` switch sets the default. So if you use it to open `fileA.pdf` - you should then be able to open `fileB.pdf` with your preferred application.

Comment: Yes. `mimeopen -d a.pdf` sets default for `*.pdf`, but it sets default for itself - `mimeopen b.pdf` works. But `xdg-open` configuration left unchanged and it still opens everything with `firefox` :/

Comment: Once I have set the default with `mimeopen`, `xdg-open` behaves as expected--in the case of `.pdf`s, it opens them with `apvlv`.

Comment: Yep, thanks. It's now working. I don't know why it didn't work before. I did same.

Comment: This doesn't work for me in Lubuntu 16.04. `sudo xdg-mime default pluma.desktop text/plain` gives `touch: cannot touch "/home/user/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list": No such file or directory
/usr/bin/xdg-mime: 807: /usr/bin/xdg-mime: cannot create /home/user/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list.new: Directory nonexistent`; `/usr/bin/vendor_perl/mimeopen -d $file.txt` gives `bash: /usr/bin/vendor_perl/mimeopen: No such file or directory`.

Answer (score 149):

Why not to use utilities from xdg itself?

To make Thunar the default file-browser, i.e. the default application for opening folders.

```
$ xdg-mime default Thunar.desktop inode/directory
```

to use xpdf as the default PDF viewer:

```
$ xdg-mime default xpdf.desktop application/pdf
```

This should create an entry

```
[Default Applications]
application/pdf=xpdf.desktop
```

in your local MIME database `~/.config/mimeapps.list`.

Your PDF files should be opened with xpdf now.

Comment: +1 and see also my related answer to the related question, http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77136/xdg-open-default-applications-behavior/107508#107508

Comment: Most useful answer, thanks. Easiest to know about `defaults.list` so it can simply be edited by hand if need be.

Comment: For some reason `xdg-mime` did not modify `defaults.list`, but editing it manually (thanks to hints in this answer) did the trick.

Comment: FYI few Perl dependencies are required for this, make sure you have them installed. RPM/DEB distributions will install these for you normally.

Comment: It seems `defaults.list` is now called `mimeapps.list`. See [the Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Default_applications#XDG_standard) for a list of valid locations for `mimeapps.list`.

Comment: To query the current default, use `xdg-mime query default application/pdf`

Comment: to figure out mimetype of a certain file run `xdg-mime query filetype pathTofileYourInterestedIn`

Comment: I found my local MIME database in `~/.config/mimeapps.list`.

Comment: @izap, you got the path to the MIME database wrong, it is `~/.config/mimeapps.list`.

Comment: On my Arch system, the right entry was `thunar.desktop` with a lowercase T, found there: `/usr/share/applications/thunar.desktop`.

Answer (score 12):

You could use something like this to generate the appropriate `xdg-mime` commands for each of your `.desktop` files and the mimetypes they contain, then execute the ones you like. Note `/usr/share/applications` might have subdirectories.

```
find /usr/share/applications ~/.local/share/applications -iname '*.desktop' -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' d; do
  for m in $(grep MimeType "$d" | cut -d= -f2 | tr ";" " "); do
    echo xdg-mime default "'$d'" "'$m'"
  done
done
```

Comment: See [user60561's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/361705/80256) if any .desktop file name contains spaces.

Comment: @Scz I copy/pasted the enhancement, I assume it works since it has been voted by 5 people. Thanks for pointing it.

Answer (score 11):

On Debian you could use the command, as root

```
update-mime-database /usr/share/mime
```

having the `shared-mime-info` package installed.

Comment: I've tried it. It doesn't work. I'm running Arch.

Comment: -1 This is specific to desktop environments that depend on shared-mime-info, such as GNOME

Answer (score 4):

For those like me that did not know how to get the proper mimetype to use with `xdg-mime`:

1- Initial situation:

`$ xdg-open .` opens vscodium (who hardcoded this stupid file association?) :[

2- Problem: what is the mime type of "."?

`$ mimetype .`
`.:      inode/directory`

3- Solution:

`$ xdg-mime default thunar.desktop inode/directory`

NOTE: Following line doesnot work but no error is reported :{
`$ xdg-mime default Thunar.desktop inode/directory`

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what everyone said, Make sure you have no overlapping applications being used.

For example let us assume you want to change the default magnet link to use qbittorrent so you type

`xdg-mime default org.qbittorrent.qBittorrent.desktop x-scheme-handler/magnet`

But when you type this and check your current default magnet

`xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/magnet`

It shows some other application for example popcorntime.desktop which isn't what you want.

**So to fix this:**

Using a File manager, go to **/usr/share/applications** and find popcorntime.desktop

Right click it and then click properties.

Go to the Applications tab.

In the **Supported file types:** area, remove the Mimetype application/x-bittorrent

Then go ahead and click ok

Notice how when you open properties again and check, you find that nothing has changed and it went back to how it was.

But it actually got deleted for a second and got reconfigured, which is why now the command

`xdg-mime default org.qbittorrent.qBittorrent.desktop x-scheme-handler/magnet`

which was already set in mimeapps.list will get applied.

Comment: Your result indicates that the `xdg-mime default` command isn't succeeding, or something is overwriting the mime database - maybe a nightly cron job? Editing distribution files in /usr/share/applications may solve the problem short term, but is a hack.