# How to open a local URL (webpage) on the command line

Tags: command-line, scripting

On MacOS X I can run

```
open /some/path/index.html
```

and this would open the page `index.html` with the default software that handles `.html` files. Is there something similar on Ubuntu Linux? I have used `gnome-open` in the past, but if there is no gnome installed, this command fails, of course.

```
gnome-open /some/path/index.html
```

Is there a generic "open this file with the default application" on Linux?

Comment: There is [`xdg-open`](http://portland.freedesktop.org/xdg-utils-1.0/xdg-open.html), [see this question for some details.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36380/how-to-properly-and-easy-configure-xdg-open-without-any-enviroment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A desktop-environment-agnostic open utility is [`xdg-open`](http://portland.freedesktop.org/xdg-utils-1.0/xdg-open.html), which could fill your need.  It's probably packaged with [some other utilities of `xdg-utils`](http://portland.freedesktop.org/wiki/).

It's discussed here quite often, see for example [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36380/how-to-properly-and-easy-configure-xdg-open-without-any-enviroment) for details on configuring it.

(Other desktop environments come with `*-open` utilities, too, e.g. there is XFCE's `exo-open`)