# xdg-open default applications behavior

Tags: arch-linux, freedesktop, defaults

When I have no `defaults.list` and `mimeapps.list`, `xdg-open` opens `text/plain` with `gvim`. But when I create `defaults.list` in `/usr/share/applications/` and add the following lines :

```
[Default Applications]
text/plain=emacs.desktop
```

it opens text files with firefox.

However, if I move `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list` to `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`, it opens text files with `emacs` as expected.

My questions:

1. How does `xdg-open` determine which application to launch when there is no `defaults.list` and `mimeapps.list`?
2. Why is `xdg-open` using firefox when I simply write `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list`?

I am using Arch linux.

Comment: I use Openbox. Also, I noticed a `/usr/share/applications/mimecache.info` file which seems to list the default applications. It is even more confusing...

Comment: I found this config file in `~/.config/mimeapps.list`

Answer (score 35):

If using `xdg-open` to open applications, then use `xdg-mime` to set the default application for a given mime type (typically, installing xdg-utils gives you the xdg-mime and related programs).

For example, to see the "filetype" (mime-type, if you will) of given file:

```
$ xdg-mime query filetype tmp.txt
text/plain

$ xdg-mime query filetype foo.pdf 
application/pdf

$ xdg-mime query filetype $PWD
inode/directory
```

Example changing the default file manager for opening directories (could choose caja.desktop (default for mint), nautilus.desktop (ubuntu), etc:

```
$ xdg-mime default Thunar.desktop inode/directory
```

And also do `locate -i foo.desktop` to verify that `foo.desktop` does in fact exist.

More to the point, in order to see what the default text editor is,

```
$ xdg-mime  query default text/plain 
gedit.desktop
```

To use a different default text editor (again, verifying that the ".desktop" file exists):

```
$ locate -i vim.desktop
/usr/share/applications/gvim.desktop

$ xdg-mime default gvim.desktop text/plain
```

Now, either double-clicking "foo.txt" (in your GUI file manager) or running `xdg-open foo.txt` will use `gvim` instead of `gedit`.

Troubleshooting: be sure that the ".desktop" file for a given application can be found, since that has to be used with the `xdg-mime` utility; e.g.,

```
$ xdg-mime default emacs text/plain 
xdg-mime: malformed argument 'emacs', expected *.desktop
```

Further, this silently fails to work as expected if the ".desktop" file does not exist:

```
$ locate -i emacs.desktop
(none)

$ xdg-mime default emacs.desktop text/plain  # won't work
```

The actual emacs ".desktop" file (in my env):

```
$ locate -r 'emacs.*\.desktop'
/usr/share/applications/emacs24.desktop

$ xdg-mime default emacs24.desktop text/plain  # does work
```

See also: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xdg-open

Comment: Years later, but Thanks! Some developer has put a really bad joke into wine, he must have thought "if you really want back some of that Windows pain, you should have it all to never get nostalgic!" And since that all X11-programs start a notepad clone when opening Text-Files. Opening files from an application is rare for me, but notepad really hurts. With your help I got back a gvim.

Comment: Similar jokes are being played on me right now, Krita, a digital painting application, is opening CSV files rather than a spreadsheet application.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh

FILETYPE=$(xdg-mime query filetype $1)
APP=$( find /usr/share -type f -name "*.desktop" -printf "%p\n" | rofi -threads 0 -dmenu -i -p "select default app")
APP=$(basename -- $APP)
xdg-mime default "$APP" "$FILETYPE"
echo "$APP set as default application to open $FILETYPE"
```

Use this script on a file, then it will ask you to choose a default app to use for this filetype.

I use `rofi`, but you can adjust it for your fuzzy finder of choice. After that, you can just open your files with `xdg-open`.