# chromium: specify file association, instead of opening file in xdg-open

Tags: chrome, xdg-open

When I click on a file in `chromium`, it calls `xdg-open` to open the file based on its mime type.

For example, if I click on a file with a `.torrent` extension, it opens it in my torrent client.

Is it possible to disable the use of `xdg-open`, and instead specify which extensions should be opened in which applications?

Comment: Chromium is opensource, so it's possible.

Comment: @Ipor Sircer - please tell me how?

Comment: @400theCat: by modifying the source but it's the hard way

Comment: Please, look into this relevant [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36380/how-to-properly-and-easy-configure-xdg-open-without-any-environment). Seems this will work in your case. @400theCat

Answer (score 0):

Changing the defaults application that `xdg-open` use, and instead specifying your own/preferred one is an easy task, and also doesn't pertain to `chromium` directly:

- Using perl-file-mimeinfo or mimeinfo

```
/usr/bin/vendor_perl/mimeopen -d $file.ext
```

which will then open a prompt where you can place the name of the wanted application, that you want to open it with.

- Using xdg tooling

```
xdg-mime default Thunar.desktop inode/directory
```

You can look into your MIME database on `~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list` or `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` to see existing entries (you can edit them, but i don't recommend to) and check what you want to change.

Refer to [the Archwiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/XDG_MIME_Applications) for more information.

Do remember that application assigned with xdg/or other method can overlap. So be wary by first running `xdg-mime query default protocol/filetype` first, or by looking into the previously mentioned MIME database directories.

Comment: I am not asking how to change `xdg` default application. I am asking how to launch application directly from chromium, without using `xdg`

Comment: So you basically want to do like what `firefox` does, and set the default application per filetype directly in chromium, without relying on `xdg`?

Comment: I just thought i would give an alternative, since `xdg` is pretty much anchored in Linux ecosystem, and while it's true that it's not the most documented piece of software, _it is_ easier to use than it look like.

Comment: exactly. I want to do like what firefox does, and set the default application per filetype directly in chromium, without relying on xdg